# Analogue of the term 'summand' for unions and intersections.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, terminology

If we have a sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i$, we call the terms $a_i$ *summands*. In fact, in the cases of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, we have a large vocabulary to describe the various components; see [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summand#See_also).

> Is there an analogue of the term 'summand' for unions and intersections?

That is, for $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$ and $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^nA_i$, is there a term which refers to the sets $A_i$?

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing a particular term for these.

Comment: I always wondered what these words were for products. Good link.

Comment: @pbs For products, I'd call them factors.

Comment: I don't know if I'd use `\displaystyle` in this post; I'd have opted for `\limits` instead. But there's no need to edit. It's just a reminder of that option, for future posts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks, I had only used `\limits` for using $\lim$ inline. I know I didn't have to edit but it does look much better.

Comment: I don't think this is by any means standard, but I'm fond of "constituent".

Answer (score 2):

I've just decided to call them "uniands", but I came here hoping there was something standard.

I believe you could get away with calling them "summands" and "factors" by analogy of $\cup$ with $+$ and $\cap$ with $\times$ (the first being the sum and product of the Boolean ring of subsets of a set, and the second being the generic terms for sum and product in a ring of any sort).

Answer (score 2):

I would go to the etymology of summand and re-engineer the word you want.
For union: 
etymology: https://www.google.com/search?q=summand+etymology

latin for union (merge): "conjugo"

So my guess is "conjugand" or something like that.

For intersection a similar guess would be: "disjungand"

Aside: I would be comfortable using "conjugand" for the parts of any commutative, associative, operator, including intersection, logical conjunction and disjunction, max, min, etc.

Comment: Operand already exists. It can apply to any operator.

Comment: Yes but in a nested expression, such as a disjunctive normal form, it is desirable to distinguish the conjugands from the disjugands.